# Python logical NOT operator for regular expressions

Tags: python, logical-operators

I tried searching for this answer online but I haven't found any luck. I am wondering if python supports a logical not operator (usually '!') in other languages for an if statement, or any control statement really. For example, I am looking to achieve this functionality.

```
if !(re.search('[0-9]', userInputVariable):
    fix error and report to user

...Proceed with rest of code...
```

Where basically if the user does not input a number I correct it to a default value and proceed with script

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `not` operator.

But that's not how you check for a number.

```
try:
  int(userInputVariable)
except ValueError:
  print "Not a number"
```

...

```
if not userInputVariable.isdigit():
```

Comment: I realize this example is a little simplistic, and thanks for the answer that is what I am looking for, but is my desired code possible, say it was a more complex regular expression that I am looking for such as checking for an email address is of correct format name@provider.domain

Comment: Your regex looks for a numeral anywhere in the string. I'm sure that as soon as you fix the regex your method will be acceptable.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for the clarity, now I see that's what Ignacio was referring to in the first line of his answer